# start second instance AWS when the first reaches 85% of memory or cpu,

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following scenario:

I have two Windows servers on AWS that run an application via IIS. For particularities of the application, they work with HTTP load balancing on the IIs.

To reduce costs, I was asked, **that the second instance is only started when the first one reaches 90% CPU usage or 85% memory usage.**

In my zone (sa-east-1), there are still no Auto Scaling Groups.

Initially, I created a cloudwatch event to start the second instance when it detected high CPU usage at first. The problem is that Cloudwatch, natively still does not monitor memory and so far I'm having trouble customizing this type of monitoring.

Is there any other way for me to be able to start the second instance based on the above conditions?

Since the first instance is always running, it might be something Windows-level, some powershell that detects the high memory usage and start the second? The script to start instances via powershell I already own, I just need help with how to detect the high memory usage event to start the second instance from it.

or some third-party application that does so...

Thanks!

Comment: According to [the AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/) Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling is available in São Paulo.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do that isn't supported.

Comment: I hope this isn't a stupid question, but you say "In my zone (sa-east-1), there are still no Auto Scaling Groups.", you do know that you have to create a Launch Configuration and an Auto Scaling Group to use the feature right? AWS doesn't handle that for you. I'm not meaning to sound cruel or anything, hope this comment doesn't come off the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

**Auto Scaling groups** are available in `sa-east-1`, so use them

**Pick *one* metric** upon which to scale (memory *OR* CPU), do not pick both otherwise it would be confusing how to scale when one metric is high and the other is low.

If you wish to **monitor Windows memory in CloudWatch**, see: [Sending Logs, Events, and Performance Counters to Amazon CloudWatch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/send_logs_to_cwl.html)

Also, be careful using a metric such as "memory usage" to measure the need to launch more instances. Some systems use garbage collection to free-up memory, but only when available memory is low (rather than continuously).

Plus, make sure your application is capable of running across multiple instances, such as putting it behind a load balancer (depending on what the application actually does).